# Upload PDF file to Express server

Tags: node.js, express, axios, multer

I've built a basic browser form allowing users to upload a PDF file. I then want to send that file to an Express backend. It seems like this should be a pretty basic action, but I'm unfamiliar with the end-to-end process so I'm not sure which piece is failing. I've searched through a number of SO questions/answers, but haven't found any that provide a complete solution, and I haven't been able to cobble together a solution either.

**Update:** It looks like the file is getting to the server, but the encoding is messed up. My guess is that `FileReader.readAsText` is the wrong method to use. `FileReader.readAsBinaryString` got me a little closer, but still not quite right (and it's deprecated). `FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer` seems like potentially the way to go, but I'm not sure how to correctly handle the buffer in Express.

**Client/Browser**

The form is built in React and just uses an `onChange` handler on the input itself. When a file has been added, the handler reads the file, adds it to the form data and sends the post request to the server.

```
// React form
<input
  name="upload"
  onChange={this._handleUpload}
  type="file"
/>

_handleUpload = (e) => {
  const { files, name } = e.target;

  // Read the file
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.result;

    // Now that we have the file's contents, append to the form data.
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    formData.append('type', name);

    axios
      .post('/upload', formData)
      .then(res => {
        // Handle the response...
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  // Reading as text. Should this be something else?
  reader.readAsText(files[0]);
}
```

**Express App**

The express app uses [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) middleware to process the upload:

```
const app = express();
const upload = multer({});

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.post('/upload', upload.any(), handleUpload);
```

**Middleware**

Finally, I have my own middleware that gets the file from multer. I'm testing this piece by just writing the file I've received to disk. It has contents, but it's not a readable PDF file.

```
const handleUpload = (req, res, next) => {
  // The file shows up on req.body instead of req.file, per multer docs.
  const { file } = req.body;

  // File is written, but it's not a readable PDF.
  const tmp = fs.writeFileSync(
    path.join(__dirname, './test.pdf'),
    file,
  );
}
```

Is there some piece that I'm getting obviously wrong here? eg: Do PDFs need to be handled in a special way? Any tips for where to focus my debugging?

Comment: The multer adds the file to the req.file(single) or req.files(any). Ex `console.log(req.files) or const {files} = req;`The body is for text only.

Comment: @AndersonMendes: I understand that, but I'm saying they don't show up there. They're actually found on `req.body`.

Comment: Ok I'll test and I'll come back.

Comment: Hi @ericgio. Can you tell me how to download the saved files from node to reactjs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**See if that solves your problem.**

```
_handleUpload = (e) => {
    const dataForm = new FormData();
    dataForm.append('file', e.target.files[0]);  
      axios
        .post('http://localhost:4000/test', dataForm)
        .then(res => {

        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));      
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
      onChange={this._handleUpload}
      type="file"
      />    
    </div>
  )
}
```

**server:**

```
router.post('/test', upload.any(), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files)
    res.send({sucess: true})
})
```

No need to send the file type, the multer identifies the name and type for you.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I mistakenly thought that I needed to read the file on the client before sending (using `FileReader`), but it turns out multer will handle all that on the other end.

Comment: Hi @justcase. Can you tell me how to download the saved files from node to reactjs